# Passing kwargs from CBV to Form in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `ModelForm` which needs a user passed in so that the queryset can be updated. I am overriding the `__init__` method of the `ModelForm` as such:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #  override init to get user's casino's EmployeeType queryset
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        print(self.user)
        super(MemoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['receiver'].queryset = EmployeeType.objects.filter(
            casino=self.user.casino
        )
```

In the `View` I have a `get` and a `post` method. I am trying to pass the `**kwargs` in as such:

```
class VideoUploadView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    """
    Display a form for uploading videos.
    """

    form_class = VideoUploadForm
    success_url = '/videos'
    template_name = 'videos/video_upload.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(
            request, 
            self.template_name,
            {'form': form, 'user': self.request.user}
        )
```

In a `CreateView` you are able to use the `get_form_kwargs` method to pass in the `**kwargs`. How is it done in a normal `View`? Should we use the `__init__` method? The way shown above does not seem to work as both `*args` and `**kwargs` seem to be empty.

[These](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.base/View/) are the built-in methods of `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you're not using a FormView here as well, so that you can still override `get_form_kwargs`; you really shouldn't ever need to define `get` (or `post`) directly.

But nevertheless, the answer is simple: you just pass your kwargs directly to the form:

```
form = self.form_class(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I used `View` because I did not know which view to use. How does one decide which view to use when it isn't apparent?

Comment: You go by functionality. If you want to create something, use a CreateView; to update, use an UpdateView, etc.

Comment: I usually do that but in this instance I was uploading a video and there is no `UploadView`. Hence the "...when it isn't apparent?" I guess I will do some more reading in this area as well. It is a lot to take in as a novice :|

Comment: Sure, but there is a generic form view for those cases.